# How to display image name after upload in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

hi i create basic page which need's to upload image. It successfully upload image but after it upload it don't displaying the name of file i upload , but it display on console . This is my `index.html` code.

This is how it's look in browser

[It display `true.png` in console but keep showing `choose file` after i upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3XTQ.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="display-3 my-2 text-center">Breast Cancer Prediction</div>
    <hr />
    {% if image_class %}
    <div class="display-4 my-2 text-center">
        <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <p>Class : {{ image_class.class }}</p>
            Confidence: {{ image_class.confidence }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-lg-12 pt">
        <form class="" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="custom-file mt-4">
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                {{ form.picture(class="file custom-file-input ") }}
                {{ form.picture.label(class="custom-file-label", for="picture") }}
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-4 text-center">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#picture').change(function(e){
  var filename = e.target.files[0].name;
  console.log(filename);
});
function displayfilename() {
  $('#picture').trigger('change');
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It displays to the console because you tell it to.

```
$('#picture').change(function(e){
  var filename = e.target.files[0].name;
  console.log(filename);
});
```

What you need to do is find the element that you're looking to list the uploads and then change the text for example

```
$('#picture').change(function(e){
      var filename = e.target.files[0].name;
      $('#picture01Desc').text(filename)
    });
```

Comment: what is `#picture01Desc` ? i use `custom-file input` and `custom-file label`.

Comment: On your UI where would you like the uploaded file to show?

Comment: The button i create to choose file i upload the image in my question.

Comment: In that case can you try $('.custom-file-label').text(filename)

Comment: hi this work `$('.custom-file-label').text(filename)` thank you.